# Derivation of matter potential from QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, neutrinos

I'm trying to derive the matter potential as experienced by neutrinos from QFT. The paper I am looking at is unfortunately not publicly available online (https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.40.259) and so I cut and paste the relevant part of the derivation I'm struggling with.

But before that, some context. I want to calculate the dispersion relation of the neutrino as it propagates in matter. Its mass is modified by the medium in which it travels.

[image]

So the loop correction is from the medium to the neutrino is:

[image]

here $f_{F}$ is the Fermi-Dirac distribution (of the electrons in the medium)
and $L$ is $P_L$, the projection operator.

I can go to the rest frame of the medium $u=(1,0,0,0)$ and use the relation
$$\delta(k^2-m_e^2)=\frac{1}{\omega_k}[\delta(k^0-\omega_k)+ \delta(k^0+\omega_k)]$$
and using

$$n_e=\int \frac{dk^3}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{e^{\beta(\omega_k\pm\mu)}+1}$$

one finds

$$S_1=\frac{g^2}{4M^2_W}(n_e-n_{\overline{e}})\gamma^0L.$$

I'm stuck on how to proceed from the first expression. Any help appreciated